# Is it possible to know all http requests possible in a web server?

Tags: http, server, request

Is it possible to know all http requests that we can do to a web server?

Edit :
And of course how to find out them?...

Comment: Once you finished counting to infinity, I'll tell you the answer.

Comment: What precisely do you mean?

Comment: Well what precisely do _you_ mean? What is "all"? Requests to /a, /b, /c, sending parameter p1=1, p1=2, ... and so on and so forth, all possible permutations (until thankfully same sensible size limit set somewhere makes an end of it) ...? Or did you perhaps mean "successful" requests, or request that actually perform some function as opposed to just firing at random to see what will happen? (Just to be clear, I am not trying to provide an answer here ... but merely to show you how ambiguous your question is. Go read [ask], please, and then edit the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot know all http requests that a web server does unless said web server offers a tool for you to know them.

If you want your web server to offer to the users a representation of your API, you can use tools like what [RAML](http://raml.org/) offers to [document your API](http://raml.org/developers/document-your-api).